# Angular 2. Can access to the service from everywhere but app.component

Tags: angular, typescript, service

It's not my first month with angular so please do not say things like "be sure if you import the service". I can call methods from the service from any component but from app.component.

No errors when importing

```
import { GeneralService } from './services/generalservice.service';
```

No errors when declaring

```
private generalService: GeneralService
```

Even if i do in @Component({......})

```
  providers: [GeneralService]
```

No errors in command line...
But for some reason browser says..

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for GeneralService: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).
at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1690)
at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15765)
at .............
```

I don't even call any function to see an error. It shows right after declaring the service in the constructor.

I just finished second Starbucks's Venti-Americano. But still no light in my brain about this... so please tell me something guys. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the service's and component's constructors codes also please?

Comment: Sure.. Service ----   constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router,
    private appComponent: AppComponent
  ) {
    this.user = afAuth.authState;
  }   ---- app.component ------    constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private generalService: GeneralService
  ) {
    this.user = afAuth.authState;
    this.profiles = db.list('/users');
    this.threadsAreLoaded = false;
    this.threadToSee = false;
  }

Comment: sorry not that pretty edited comment. but i don't know how ))

Comment: You injected the component in the service? Plus it makes a circular call

Comment: Where is the `GeneralService` declared? In Shared module? App module?
I would first make sure it's declared in the App module.

Comment: Vega .... Thank YOU!!!!! copy paste issue. didn't noticed that))) to much coffee, to much starbucks...)))

Comment: Catalyst in app module. thanks for reaching out, solved.

Comment: You are welcome. I stopped the coffee btw:)

Comment: Vega me too, but i've to finish this project by tomorrow or.. well, problems))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inject a service to `AppComponent`, the services needs to be provided in `@Component(...)` of `AppComponent` or in `@NgModule(...)` of a non-lazy-loaded module.

Comment: Gunter   It is in @NgModule, it was about some additional line in declarations, thanks.

Comment: The problem is in the constructor of `GeneralService` or with its 3 dependencies required by the constructor, they also need to be provided at the same level as `GeneralService` or higher.

Comment: My guess it's about declaring component in the constructor of service as Vega said -- private appComponent: AppComponent. this line is removed and now everything works again!)) about providing them at the same level or higher - they are on the same level.